# Optimising one parameter so that an output lies between two points

Tags: python, optimization

I have this code where I need to try and keep the output of my battery between being fully depleted and fully charged by weighting (using wind_throttle) a constant (wind_power_annuum) differently for each timestep. So I guess this is an optimisation question with bounds.

It's quite important and I'm quite upset as I thought I had this project finished but I noticed an error in my code that gave me results that LOOKED correct, but upon further inspection it was very much incorrect! **Instead of adding the difference to the previous timestep, it was resetting itself to a misplaced variable. So fluctuation that I expected was there but the values were incorrect. The code below is corrected now from that previous iteration, but now the problem is in the requirement to throttle a power parameter so it remains within the bounds of my battery.**

So I would really really apprecciate help and guidance. I will post the code and the files for review below, along with a picture which I hope will describe the problem.

As always, thank you for your time. I really apprecciate the time you guys take out of your day to help someone out!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IpOBNz1TQHAqxyG_E2qwERhIdigxzzzB

- Contains data for np.load() so you dont have to generate anything new. Just save in relevant folder.
- Contains code posted below.
- Contains picture. Battery in above plot. Load (Red) and Supply (Blue) below.

**I have updated the battery function below with an attempt at a solution. It is currently running and taking a good long while as it is rather a brute force approach!**

```
import numpy as np  # Initial code posted to Overflow 
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

Battery_Charge_Initial = 6.9 # kWh = Fully Charged with 13.8 kW output 55 mins of output per battery (x3) 
Battery_Max = 13.8
timebase = 1440*365
t0 = 0

load = np.load('load_power_anuum.npy')
supply = np.load('wind_power_anuum.npy')*(wind_throttle) + np.load('solar_power_anuum.npy')*2

#def wind_throttle(): #ahbdbwasdxSOS
#    for t in range(timebase):
 #       if

def battery():

    charge = np.zeros(timebase) 
    value = np.array ( range(timebase), dtype = float) 
    supply_zero = np.zeros(timebase)
    value = (supply-load)*(1/60)

    charge[0] = Battery_Charge_Initial

    for t in range(1,timebase):
            charge[t] = charge[t-1] + value[t]

    return charge

ts = np.arange( t0, 1440*365, 1)
Batt = battery()

plot_type = 1
figure = pyplot.figure()

if plot_type == 0:
    print ( " Plot type cannot equal zero! Please select a the relevant plot type" )

elif plot_type == 1:
    pyplot.subplot(211)
    pyplot.plot(ts, Batt, color = 'black', linewidth = 0.5)
    pyplot.ylabel("Battery kWh") 
    pyplot.xlabel("Time (Minutes)")
    pyplot.ylim(-0.05,13.85)
    pyplot.legend()

    pyplot.subplot(212)
    pyplot.plot(ts, supply, color = 'b', linewidth = 0.5)
    pyplot.plot(ts, load, color = 'r', linewidth = 0.5)
    pyplot.ylabel("Power kW") 
    pyplot.xlabel("Time (Minutes)") 
    pyplot.legend()

if plot_type > 0:
```

---

```
def battery():

    charge = np.zeros(timebase) 
    value = np.array ( range(timebase), dtype = float)
    wind_throttle = np.array( range(timebase), dtype = float)
    charge[0] = Battery_Charge_Initial
    supply = np.zeros(timebase)

    for t in range(1,timebase):
        if t == 0:
            charge[t] = charge[t]
        else:
            wind_throttle[t] = 1.00
            supply[t] = wind_power[t]*(wind_throttle[t]) + solar_power[t]*2
            value[t] = (supply[t]-load[t])*(1/60)
            charge[t] = charge[t-1] + value[t]
            while charge[t] >= Battery_Max or charge[t] <= 0.00:
                wind_throttle[t] = random.random()
                if 0.00 < charge[t] <= Battery_Max:
                    break

    return charge, wind_throttle, supply
```

Comment: *"upon further inspection it was very much incorrect!"* incorrect in what way? Describe the problem more specifically, and give an example of input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: I have updated my post but that isn't where the problem lies now as that was an error I have corrected myself. However, in correcting it, I realised that I was overcharging my battery or simply draining it dry. So now, I have set my code up so that my supply with parameter wind_throttle = 1, will always exceed the load, but I wish to vary that parameter so that my supply matches my load as close as possible, within the range of the capabilites of the battery. I hope that along with my edits and potential solution update is helpful.